# Find $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} f\left(\frac{nx}{1+nx}\right)\,dx$

Tags: integration, limits

> Let $f: [0,\infty) \to [0, \infty)$ be monotone increasing. Find 
>   $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} f\left(\frac{nx}{1+nx}\right)\,dx$$

I'm pretty sure I can't just bring the limit inside of the integral. We don't know enough about $f$.

This problem is from a section about switching limits and integrals, but everything in this section dealt with sequences of Riemann integrable functions $f_n(x)$ that converge uniformly to $f$. Then
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{a}^{b} f_n(x) dx = \int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx.$$

So, my thought is to construct a sequence of functions. 
Let $f_n(x) = f\left(\frac{nx}{1+nx}\right).$ Then $f_n(x)$ converges uniformly to $f(x)$.

So then
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} f_n(x) dx = \int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx.$$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} f\left(\frac{nx}{1+nx}\right) dx = \int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx.$$

I've completely ignored monotone increasing, so something is wrong?

Comment: "Let $f_n(x) = f\left(\frac{nx}{1+nx}\right).$ Then $f_n(x)$ converges uniformly to $f(x)$." Are you absolutely sure about that?

Comment: Uhh, no. It doesn't, actually. >_>

Comment: I don't see a summation here. Am I losing it when I say that $f(\frac{nx}{1+nx})$ looks more like $1$ than $x$ for large $n$?

Comment: Yeah it looks like 1. I'm losing it apparently. :P

Comment: It looks even more like $f(1).$

Comment: Is $f$ continuous?

Comment: It was not an assumption that $f$ is continuous. (Perhaps assumptions are missing from the original source.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $f_n(x)$ as you have. That is, $$f_n(x) = f\left(\frac{nx}{nx+1}\right) = f\left(\frac{1}{\frac{1}{nx}+1}\right).$$

We note that the function argument monotonically increases to $1$, i.e., $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{nx}+1} = 1; \qquad \frac{1}{\frac{1}{nx}+1} \leq \frac{1}{\frac{1}{mx}+1}, n\leq m.$$

Therefore, by the monotonicity of $f$ we know that $f_n(x)$ increases monotonically to $f(1) := \lim_{x \to 1^-}f(x)$. And since $f(1)$ is finite, it is an integrable constant on a set of finite measure, i.e., $$\int_0^1|f(1)|dx < \infty.$$ Hence by monotone convergence theorem we can interchange the limit and integral.

Comment: It had domain $[0, \infty)$, but someone edited it to $[0,1)$ apparently.

Comment: $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}$ monotonically increases, but $\lim_{x\to 1^-}f(x)=\infty$.

Comment: Apparently the OP edited to extend the domain.  Disregard the previous comment.

Comment: @Dr.MV Yes that was confusing to me, when I began answering the question I believed that the domain was not an issue. Then I wrote the answer and it was. Then I edited the answer and it no longer was.

Comment: (+1) for the "Final Answer."  Interestingly, $f$ can have a jump discontinuity at $x=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Split it to two integrals $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1/\sqrt n} f\left(\frac{nx}{1+nx}\right) dx + \int_{1/\sqrt n}^{1} f\left(\frac{nx}{1+nx}\right) dx$$
First integral is zero and second goes to f(1) when n goes huge

Comment: Do we know that $f(1)$ exists?

Comment: @Dr. MV Oh, didn't read it right, tought domen is (0,infty). Then it must be infinity, I will edit the answer

Comment: Apparently the OP edited to extend the domain.  Disregard the previous comment.

Comment: @Dr. MV I see, anyway answer is infinity cos we can always pick n so $\sqrt n/(1+\sqrt n)$ be close enough to 1